# PHPExcel showing unreadable character

Tags: joomla, phpexcel

```
function districtexcelpdf(){

    ob_start();
    require_once('districtexcel.php');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExceldis();       
    $objPHPExcel->districtExcel();

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="District_report.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');


    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); 
    header ('Pragma: public'); 

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    ob_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
}
```

In above code I got a unreadable character . Required help to solve this problem.

Comment: What is a `PHPExceldis` object? Is this some type of wrapper that you have around the PHPExcel object?

Comment: PHPExceldis is a class in districtexcel.php which extends PHPExcel

Comment: So explain what is happening.... when you run this through your browser, what happens? Is anything written to PHP logs?

Comment: Excel is downloading but its shows unreadable character . I tried by writing something and vice versa in districtexcel.php but it shows same problem.

Comment: You mean it shows a message saying "unreadable character" when you try to open the file in MS Excel?

Comment: hey Mark i got the the answer before ob_start(); i used ob_clean(); because it sending the junk value i believe. I need perfect answer from you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ob_clean(); at the start because it sending a junk value then after use ob_start(); and at the end ob_clean();